# Fuseki 2 transactions via endpoint

Tags: sparql, jena, fuseki

I found this document when searching for the ways to have transactions working in Fuseki 2: http://people.apache.org/~sallen/sparql11-transaction/

It describes special endpoint /transaction. The description sounds like good design for SPARQL transaction support.

Does anyone know how to have this /transaction endpoint configured for Fuseki 2 server?
Since the document originates in Apache Jena it should be the way to do that, right?

Comment: You don't have to configure anything special. Fuseki uses transactions, nothing more nothing less. For usage of Fuseki, use the [docs](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/)

Comment: That document was a proposal dated from 2014 and that AFAIK was never implemented or adopted in Fuseki.  As @AKSW points out Fuseki already includes transaction support provided that the underlying database supports it (which the Fuseki default database does)